# Example ASP.NET MVC3 apps with unit tests

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

What are some good example (FOSS) ASp.NET MVC3 apps that come with unit tests to use as examples / learn from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Nerd Dinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) (there is a MVC3-Razor branch).